# Coldfusion and Associative Arrays

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, associative-array

I am used to handling my associative arrays PHP style, where I would have something like the following

```
array[day][time] = count
```

This allows me to easily count the number of times something appears and its an easy structure to work with. In my case here, I am reading a resultset from a database and getting something like this to work would be really helpful

How would I do the same type of thing in Coldfusion?

Comment: Just as a side note - PHP associative arrays are ordered while CF structs _are not_. If you need to rely on the order of the items in the struct, you will need to implement a Java HashMap.

Comment: More specifically, a LinkedHashMap for preserving key created date order, TreeMap for sorting keys by an algorithm of your choice or HashMap which is internally ordered efficiently which looks like it's random.

Comment: Associative arrays in cf are generally called 'structs'. `struct[day][time] = count` interprets day and time as variables. To set them as new keys, wrap them in quotes. `struct['day']['time'] = count`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a structure to me - and you can create it easily the way you are used to:

```
<cfscript>

   myStruct = { day= { time = count}};

</cfscript>
```

Or using the old syntax which perhaps outlines it better.

```
<cfset mySTruct = structNew()/>
<Cfset mySTruct.day = structNew()/>
<Cfset myStruct.day.time = count/>
```

Remember too that a ColdFusion query object is already an exceedingly useful little data construct with a format of queryName[struct][row] - and query of a query (where you can utilize SQL to simply query a query object) allows easy access to this data as well.

Hope this helps you Reg. Good luck.

Comment: And struct support the bracket notation as well but you need to provide them in quotes: myStruct['day']['count'] = x; If you are ColdFusion 9.01+, you can implicity define the struct simply by using it: <cfset myStruct['day']['count'] = count><cfdump var="#mystruct#">

Comment: Well, 'day' ,'time', and 'count' are dynamic values (I should have been clearer).

Comment: Reg - do you mean something like :     mystruct['11/20/2010']['4:00 am'] = 1234;     ... if so you *can* do that (using bracket notation) but it might give you a bit of heartburn. not sure if it's a great idea in *either* language :)

Comment: It would be something similar to this. I have sort of got it working (#data[qView.adate][qView.time]#), but I am not sure how to check that the variable is initialized

Comment: see this post for some helpful tips on this topic. http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2005/9/8/isdefined%20vs%20structkeyexists

Comment: or just dot into it without calling `structNew()`. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a followup to a comment Reginold had about checking whether the struct is defined:

```
<cfset thisvar = '04/MAR/2012'>
<cfset thatvar = '04:11'>
<cfset myStruct[thisvar][thatvar] = 'test'>

<!--- Check first key, then second --->
<cfif structKeyExists(myStruct,thisvar) and structKeyExists(mystruct[thisvar],thatvar)>
    Both Keys Exist.<hr>
</cfif>

<!--- Alternative Check --->
<cfif isDefined('myStruct.#thisvar#.#thatvar#') >
    Key Exists.<hr>
</cfif>

<cfdump var="#myStruct#">
```

Comment: I changed your variable names since `this` is a reserved word (refers to public vars in a cfc), and hence could cause errors/confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Coldfusion arrays, too.

```
array = [[], []];// initialize array

array[1][1] = 1;// set a value in the array
```

Just remember that Coldfusion arrays start at an index of 1, not 0.